# LZW data decompression algorithm

Tags: algorithm, compression

I've been studying the [LZW algorithm](http://www.cs.duke.edu/csed/curious/compression/lzw.html)  for data compression since recently. I've understood the encoding algorithm, however, I cant make any sense the the decoding algorithm which converts the encoded data back into it's original form.

Following is the pseudocode for the decoder taken from [here](http://www.cs.duke.edu/csed/curious/compression/lzw.html)

```
string entry;
char ch;
int prevcode, currcode;
...

prevcode = read in a code;
decode/output prevcode;
while (there is still data to read)
{
  currcode = read in a code;
  entry = translation of currcode from dictionary;
  output entry;
  ch = first char of entry;
  add ((translation of prevcode)+ch) to dictionary;
  prevcode = currcode;
}
```

I'm looking for a step-by-step explanation of this code.

**EDIT:** What I dont understand is this: Why do we have 3 different strings, namely *entry*, *prevcode* and *currcode* ? In my opinion, one should be the encoded string and the second should be the output string which is created. So what is the third string doing there?

Secondly I really dont understand the purpose of ***(translation of prevcode)+ch*** in the second last line of the code.

Thanks.

Comment: The [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Welch) has a complete walkthrough of encoding and decoding. What exactly is troubling you?

Comment: One conceptual problem is that the "state" of the decoder includes bits left over from the previous call -- it's not a simple 1,2,3 process with separable steps.

Comment: @Paul Rubel I've edited my question to express my problem more clearly. Hope that's enough.

Comment: It is to prevent the "exception" from occuring. Read http://marknelson.us/category/data-compression/

Answer (score 2):

If you understand the compression part you should also be able to understand that for decompression to work, the decompressor needs to rebuild the compression table from the decompressed data exactly like it was built during compression - otherwise the codes coming in that are not plain character codes will be meaningless. That is what these extra statements do.